# Select count date from multiple where conditions for each day

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I have lot of coupons. I would like to learn for each day how many coupons from each campaign have been received by users. But I cannot write something like assigned_date for each select row

```
SELECT count(id)                                                  as number_of_coupons,
       DATE_FORMAT(assigned_date, '%d-%m-%Y')                     as date,
       (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM coupon WHERE campaign_id = 1 AND assigned_date=THIS MUST BE SOMETHING) as campaign_1,
       (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM coupon WHERE campaign_id = 2 AND assigned_date=THIS MUST BE SOMETHING) as campaign_2
FROM coupon
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(assigned_date, '%d-%m-%Y')
order by STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d-%m-%Y') DESC
```

So the result will be something like. How can I achieve this result?

```
+-------------------+------------+-------------+-----------+
| number of coupons |    date    |  campaign_1 | campaign2 |
+-------------------+------------+-------------+-----------+
|               156 | 12-10-2019 |        6980 |       100 |
|               177 | 11-10-2019 |        6980 |       100 |
|                44 | 10-10-2019 |        6980 |       100 |
|                94 | 09-10-2019 |        6980 |       100 |
|                93 | 08-10-2019 |        6980 |       100 |
+-------------------+------------+-------------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT count(id)                                       as number_of_coupons,
       DATE_FORMAT(assigned_date, '%d-%m-%Y')          as date,
       SUM(CASE WHEN campaign_id=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  as campaign_1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN campaign_id=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  as campaign_2
FROM coupon
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(assigned_date, '%d-%m-%Y')
order by STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d-%m-%Y') DESC
```

Comment: Why SUM works fine but COUNT gives the same campaign_1 campaign_2 count?

Comment: You have to ADD all the ones and zeros together.     check output of `select assigned_date, CASE WHEN campaign_id=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as campaign_1, CASE WHEN campaign_id=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  as campaign_2 FROM coupon`

Comment: You are doing a sub-select over another "copy" of the coupon table, and that copy is not correlated to the main one.  With Luuk's version there is no sub-select going on.